# PHP is not synchronizing correctly with MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a PHP webpage that connects to a MySQL database. Both are on the same server. The problem is that when i made the first connection to the database everything was fine. Later on I had to change some fields through phpMyAdmin. After I did this I went back to my PHP page and made a new connection to the database. My surprise was that everything is like the first time I connected.

Now, I really have spend a good amount of time reading and searching around and supposedly I am doing everything pretty correct. I understand that I have to close the connection of the PDO object after the job is done by setting the object to NULL. This is done, but still nothing happens.

From what I have read everyone and everything points to the $_SESSION variable and that the connection has to be closed properly.

**For this reason I have tried to log in/connect from another computer, a completely different system, navigate to my webpage, use the script to login, and the result is the same. The old data keeps populating, and what I see/have in phpMyAdmin is absolutely different.**

So I can't understand how is this going to be a session problem when I am logging from a completely different location, just the same script on my page.

Please if anyone can suggest what is going on it will be great.

Here is the script I use to connect to the database and display the results:

```
<?php

echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>CatId</th><th>Title</th><th>Introtext</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
}

function current() {
    return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
} 

function endChildren() { 
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
} 
} 

$servername = htmlspecialchars($_POST["hostname"]);
$database = htmlspecialchars($_POST["database"]);
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
$tab = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tab"]);

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, catid, title, introtext FROM $tab"); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using `htmlspecialchars()` is a bad idea

Comment: @Dagon, do you mean that this may be the problem?

Comment: no, just could be in the future. your particular problem is odd, but i dont see how to diagnose the issue with out direct access.

Comment: have you seen this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2843/why-is-mysql-caching-data-on-our-dynamic-php-site? It shows you how to check if you have caching on.

Comment: Perhaps you're connecting to two different database servers (which commonly happens if you've installed MySQL manually and as part of a kit like XAMPP), or to two different systems completely, or as two different users. Try issuing the `STATUS;` command from each connection to verify hostname, connection type, etc.

Comment: @Terminus, very well, it seems that this should be the right direction, but right now I can't make a test because unfortunately my host provider is using a phpMyAdmin version that doesn't have "Privilege" options and I can't set SUPER user privileges so I can change the cache type like this: `SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 0;` Now I'm facing this other problem and I hope I will find a work around ASAP so I can confirm if this is the issue, which most probably will be!

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch, checked that, all is correct. I have only one database on the host and i'm not using XAMPP, neither a manual MySQL installation, it comes with my host. Besides that I have pulled the data correctly the first time, but after that, whenever I connect with the PHP script it shows that same information I pulled the first time, and in phpMyAdmin I have made some new changes that doesn't reflect.

Comment: Is there a chance you or your host is implementing a cache or proxy on outbound traffic? I wonder if the result page itself is getting cached somewhere between the webserver and your browser. I didn't notice anything obviously wrong in your code. You might also try a complete dump of the results of `select * from __` where you hardcode the table name just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch, @Dagon, @Terminus, problem solved. Just wanted to say thanks for your time and help anyway. FYI the problem was "me" actually! First of all I haven't posted the exact code I use in the script and that mislead all of you, and me too :/ . However, to the point, the problem is that I was using the SQL `LIMIT` function for each row I try to pull the data. And as you may already suggest, it was returning the rows as they are in the SQL, not by the ID that I have in the ID column, and thus not in the same order, as SQL doesn't use numbers to order the records. That was the problem.

Comment: For this to work one must pull the data and later on order again by ID number through the script.